# Where do Existing Quote Records Go after Quotes are Disabled?

Tags: quote, quotelineitem

We need to disable Quotes in our org. Standard [**help**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=quotes_enable.htm&type=0) does not provide information on what happens with Quote records and related Quote Line Items after Quotes are disabled.

I assume the existing Quote records will be deleted, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in my developer org, and the answer is apparently: nothing. The object itself is disabled, but the quote records do not "go" anywhere. I've turned it off and on a few times, and no data was deleted. However, please note that you won't be able to disable quotes until you delete all classes, triggers, custom fields, custom buttons, etc that are related to quotes, so if you have a lot of customization, you may still end up losing data.

Comment: @EduardY. You're welcome! Fortunately, all of my data is just dummy data, but make sure you back up anything you care about in those objects.